# Can't Change Brightness on Ubuntu 22.04.2 on Start Up Only

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, brightness

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 and whenever I turn on my computer, I'm unable to change the brightness using the keyboard keys. However, I can change the brightness using the slider in the top right corner. The weird part is that when my PC goes to sleep (not turned off) automatically (and not manually, when I press `Super+L`) and I turn it back on, I'm able to change the brightness with the keyboard.

I have intel CPU & Graphics on a Lenovo laptop.

Here's my `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```